# How to set alignment for layout in android with localization?

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, localization

I have used localization in my android application. Which supports two kind of layout in application.

I have used Fragment and Fragment Activity in my application.

If language is English then layout should be aligned to left as shown in image below.

[image: Left Aligned Layout]

And if language is Hebrew then layout should be aligned to right as shown in image below.

[image: Right Aligned Layout]

I am trying to load this layout by two different layout files and then I can detect which language and I can use appropriately.

Is there any other good methodology through I can use achieve this functionality without creating different XMLs for all layouts?

Can anybody please help me to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This should help:
http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html#RTL

Android supports right-to-left layouts natively since android 4.2.

Answer (score 0):

**Creating two similar layouts those are having same `@+id` values is a clean approach** but if you don't want to create two different layouts then you could simply set the `layout_gravity` attribute by code with some helper method and by getting the `LayoutParams` of the containers you are using in your **xmls**.

**Edit :**

From another answer , If it works for you with the support package i.e. **v4** if you are targeting **2.2+** above then this would be an awesome approach to go with.

http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html#RTL

just came to know about this. Android is awesome!!